# Predict whether a message will be starred or not in 50 bytes

Tags: classification, test-battery

Given an input of a string consisting of any message from [our site
chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) taken
from the list described and linked below, output either a truthy or a falsy
value attempting to predict whether that message was starred or not in 50 bytes
or less.

You may use any [truthy or falsy
values](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/3808), but they must be
identical (i.e. there should only be two possible outputs, one truthy and one
falsy). The input will be given as raw HTML with newlines removed, and it may
contain non-ASCII Unicode characters. If you require input in something other
than UTF-8, please say so in your answer.

The winning submission to this challenge will be the one that predicts the
highest percentage of chat messages correctly, out of the list linked below. If
two given submissions have the same success rate, the shorter submission will
win.

Please provide instructions for running your code on the entire set of messages
and calculating the percentage correct. Ideally, this should be a bit of
boilerplate code (not counted towards your 50 bytes) that loops through the
positive test cases and outputs how many of them your code got correct and then
does the same for the negative test cases. (The overall score can then be
calculated manually via `(correctPositive + correctNegative) / totalMessages`.)

So that your code is reasonably testable, it must complete in 5 minutes or less
for the entire list of chat messages on reasonable modern-day hardware.

[The full list of chat messages can be found
here](https://gist.github.com/KeyboardFire/99f3c1d5c67c999ba59e), and it
consists of the 1000 latest starred messages as truthy test cases and the 1000
latest unstarred messages as falsy test cases. Note that there are two files in the gist; scroll about halfway down for the unstarred messages.

Comment: Knowing the behaviors of chat, I think the following Pyth would suffice: `O2`

Comment: Considering the history of past starred messages, Regex, 11 bytes: `Don'?t star`

Comment: What kind of encoding is used in the test files (utf-8 right?)? Whatever I try, I always get more than 1000 lines. Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I think I get it: When there are messages with code (those with `<pre>` and `<br>`) all those linebreaks within are carriage returns `\r` and *not* newlines. But when we download these files, it seems there will be `\n`s inserted. Suggestion @Doorknob : Remove the `\r`s from your testfiles.

Comment: This would be much easier if you were also given the user as part of the input.

Comment: And whether I was online at that time?

Comment: At some point I would've answered __Regex, 2 bytes__ `\^`

Comment: The title should have been something like: "Don't star this challenge"

Comment: +1 for good challenge, -1 for "Do X in Y bytes". Solid sidevote here.

Comment: I think you should run this again on the next 1,000 messages, and see which one *really* predicted starredness

Comment: @mego i usually would agree with this but it seems like the best way to do [tag:test-battery]

Comment: Random question: how did you compile these lists?

Comment: by what starring is defined? and how to access it? BTW -1 for not a real coding but more a "know your api" challange. Since I as embedded developer have not even a chance to create a body that would inspect the input in under 50 bytes (C and C++ here...)

Comment: @Zaibis See the last paragraph. Why can't you use C? There's only a few bytes of boilerplate (`int f(char*s){}`).

Comment: @ETHproductions I wrote a short Ruby script to scrape the transcript URLs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 50 bytes, <s>71.8%</s> 72.15%

```
^.*([[CE;ಠ-ﭏ]|tar|ol|l.x|eo|a.u|pin|nu|o.f|"$)
```

Tried some regex golfing at @MartinBüttner's suggestion. This matches 704 starred messages and doesn't match 739 unstarred messages.

The `^.*( ... )` is to make sure that there is always either 0 or 1 match, since Retina outputs the number of matches by default. You can score the program on the input files by prepending `` m` `` for multiline mode, then running

```
Retina stars.retina < starred.txt
```

and likewise for `unstarred.txt`.

---

#### Analysis / explanation

I generated the above snippets (and many more) using a program, then selected the ones I wanted manually. Here's some intuition as to why the above snippets work:

- `C`: Matches `PPCG`, `@CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ`
- `E`: Matches `@ETHproductions`, `@El'endiaStarman`
- `;`: Because the test cases are HTML, this matches `&lt;` and `&gt;`
- `ಠ-ﭏ`: Matches a range of Unicode characters, most prominently for `ಠ_ಠ` and `@Doorknob冰`
- `tar`: Matches variations of `star`, `@El'endiaStarman` (again) and also `gravatar` which appears in the oneboxes posted by new posts bots
- `ol`: Matches `rel="nofollow"` which is in a lot of links and oneboxes
- `l.x`: Matches `@AlexA.`, `@trichoplax`
- `eo`: Mainly matches `people`, but also three cases for `@Geobits`
- `a.u`: Mainly matches `graduation`, `status`, `feature` and `abuse`
- `pin`: Matches `ping` and words ending in `ping`. Also matches a few posts in a discussion about `pineapple`, as an example of overfitting.
- `nu`: Matches a mixed bag of words, the most common of which is `number`
- `o.f`: Matches `golf`, `conf(irm|use)`
- `"$`: Matches a double quote as a last character, e.g. `@phase He means "Jenga."`

The `[` is nothing special - I just had a character left over so I figured I could use it to match one more case.

Comment: (I haven't posted the testing code yet because it seems to be running rather slowly, and I'd like to figure out why. It's too late now though.)

Comment: Executing Retina once for each test case will take a long time. Multi-line mode reports the claimed score pretty much instantly.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I completely forgot I could do that.

Comment: LOL, now *my* name is a star magnet?

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript ES6, 50 bytes, 71.10%

Correctly identifies 670 starred and 752 non-starred.

```js
x=>/ .[DERv]|tar|a.u|l.x|<i|eo|ol|[C;ಠ]/.test(x)
```

Now across the 70% barrier, and beating everyone except Retina!

Returns `true` if the message contains any of these things:

- A word of which the second letter is `D`, `E`, `R`, or `v`;
- `tar` (usually `star`);
- `a` and `u` with one char in between;
- `l` and `x` with one char in between (usually `alex`);
- italic text;
- `eo` or `ol`;
- a `C`, a semicolon, or a `ಠ`.

Here's a few more fruitful matches that don't seem to be worth getting rid of others:

- `nf`
- `nu`
- `yp`
- `n.m`

This has been growing closer and closer to the Retina answer, but I have found most of the improvements on my own.

Test it out in the console of one of these pages: [star texts](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KeyboardFire/99f3c1d5c67c999ba59e/raw/7a6af1d79d39af2ee2c25605407cec3bc9cb1c63/starred.txt), [no-star texts](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KeyboardFire/99f3c1d5c67c999ba59e/raw/7a6af1d79d39af2ee2c25605407cec3bc9cb1c63/unstarred.txt)

```js
var r=document.body.textContent.replace(/\n<br/g,"<br").split("\n").slice(0,-1);
var s=r.filter(function(x){return/ .[DERv]|tar|a.u|l.x|<i|eo|ol|[C;ಠ]/.test(x)}).length;
console.log("Total:",r.length,"Matched:",s,"Not matched:",r.length-s);
```

---

Here's an alternate version. `/a/.test` is technically a function, but doesn't satisfy [our criteria](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/42545):

```js
/ .[ERv]|a.u|l.x|<i|eo|yp|ol|nf|tar|[C;ÿ-ﬀ]/.test
```

This scores 71.90% (697 starred, 741 unstarred).

---

I've been running some analyses on the lists to see which regex groups match the most starred and the least unstarred posts. The analyses can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ETHproductions/425cbf398353684b37bd). So far, I've checked `aa` and `a.a` matches. `a.u` is down at around #50 with a score of 28, yet it's the most efficient match of its format...

Comment: There are only 1000 messages...?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Some were multi-line, which wasn't accounted for in the snippet. This has been fixed.

Comment: Why no one uses `/regexp/.test()`? I think it's possible to squeeze in a few more cases with that.

Comment: Today I learned I can get chat stars just by saying my own name.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Thanks, dunno how I didn't think of that

Comment: Quick question: would `f=/t[ao]r|l.x|bo[tx]|a.u|ol|<.>|[C;ÿ-ﬀ]/.test` count as a valid answer?

Comment: @BojidarMarinov Thanks for the suggestion, but that throws an error for me. However, `/t[ao]r|l.x|bo[tx]|a.u|ol|<.>|[C;ÿ-ﬀ]/.test` seems borderline, since you can still call it like `("test")`...

Comment: I don't think this is valid [by our current consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/8478) "The submitted code should either define a named function or evaluate to **an unnamed function which can be captured in a name if desired (or if the language provides other mechanisms which allow the function to be used *multiple times without repeating its definition).***"

Comment: @MartinBüttner That makes sense. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ cc ^

Answer (score 15):

## Pyth, 50 bytes, 67.9 %

```
0000000: 21 40 6a 43 22 03 91 5d d3 c3 84 d5 5c df 46 69 b5 9d  !@jC"..]....\.Fi..
0000012: 42 9a 75 fa 74 71 d9 c1 79 1d e7 5d fc 25 24 63 f8 bd  B.u.tq..y..].%$c..
0000024: 1d 53 45 14 d7 d3 31 66 5f e8 22 32 43 7a              .SE...1f_."2Cz
```

This hashes the input in one of 322 buckets and chooses the Boolean depending on that bucket.

#### Scoring

```
$ xxd -c 18 -g 1 startest.pyth
0000000: 72 53 6d 21 40 6a 43 22 03 91 5d d3 c3 84 d5 5c df 46  rSm!@jC"..]....\.F
0000012: 69 b5 9d 42 9a 75 fa 74 71 d9 c1 79 1d e7 5d fc 25 24  i..B.u.tq..y..].%$
0000024: 63 f8 bd 1d 53 45 14 d7 d3 31 66 5f e8 22 32 43 64 2e  c...SE...1f_."2Cd.
0000036: 7a 38                                                  z8
$ echo $LANG
en_US
$ pyth/pyth.py startest.pyth < starred.txt
[[345, False], [655, True]]
$ pyth/pyth.py startest.pyth < unstarred.txt
[[703, False], [297, True]]
```

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, 45 bytes, 65.55%

```
l_c"\"#&'(-.19<CEFHIJLMOPSTXY[_qಠ"e=\1b8672>|
```

This checks if the first character is in a specific list or the sum of all code points is larger than 8,672.

#### Scoring

```
$ cat startest.cjam
1e3{l_c"\"#&'(-.19<CEFHIJLMOPSTXY[_qಠ"e=\1b8672>|}*
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar startest.cjam < starred.txt | fold -1 | sort | uniq -c
    308 0
    692 1
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar startest.cjam < unstarred.txt | fold -1 | sort | uniq -c
    619 0
    381 1
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the `fold` command, along with the actual answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab/Octave, 17 bytes 60.15%

**Correctly classifies 490 messages as stared, 713 messages as unstared**

Current version:

Just checking the length.

```
f=@(w)numel(w)>58
```

Old version:

Could be translated to any other language. It just checks whether the message contains the words *star* or not. `score: 59/911/52.5%`

```
f=@(w)nnz(strfind(lower(w),'star'))>0 %
```

Results for testcases using this code:

```
slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8');

fid = fopen('codegolf_starred_messages_starred.txt');
line = fgetl(fid);
starred = 0;
while ischar(line)
    if f(line);
        starred = starred +1;
    end

    disp(line)
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);


fid = fopen('codegolf_starred_messages_unstarred.txt');
line = fgetl(fid);
unstarred = 0;
while ischar(line)
    if ~f(line);
        unstarred = unstarred +1;
    end

    disp(line)
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);

disp(['  correctly classified as *ed: ',num2str(starred)])
disp(['correctly classified as un*ed: ',num2str(unstarred)])
disp(['                  total score: ',num2str((starred+unstarred)/20),'\%'])
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 0.615 = 61.5%

342 correctly identified as starred, 888 correctly identified as unstarred, `(342+888)/2000 = 0.615`

```
x=>-~x.search(/(bo|le)x|sta|ಠ|ツ/i)
```

Test like this on [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KeyboardFire/99f3c1d5c67c999ba59e/raw/7a6af1d79d39af2ee2c25605407cec3bc9cb1c63/unstarred.txt) or [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KeyboardFire/99f3c1d5c67c999ba59e/raw/7a6af1d79d39af2ee2c25605407cec3bc9cb1c63/starred.txt):

```
r=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\/*pre>/g,"").split`
`.filter(x=>-~x.search`(bo|le)x|sta|ಠ|ツ`).length
```

<sub>I STILL MIGHT GET YOU, MY PRETTY!</sub>

Comment: I've got you now ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions GG. I'll look for some more common patterns.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 32 bytes, Overall score of 0.5605 (56%).

Correctly identifies 428 starred messages and 693 unstarred messages. Total score is `(360+730)/2000=0.545`.

```
l_el"sta"/,1>\,)4%!|
```

Not expecting to win, Ill see how it performs. Above is the code for a single message, to run with multiple use this modified version that returns amount of starred messages:

```
1000{l_el"star"/,1>\,)6%!|}fA]:+
```

Just test it with STDIN being the raw text of either file. Returns true if the message contains "star" or if `length + 1 mod 4 = 0`.

Comment: So... if four divides one more than the length of a message, then it has a chance of being starred?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes, but it provides for a high score

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, 46 bytes, 68.55

```
^.*([zj_C;&¡-ﬀ]|sta|san|soc|bo|eo|xk|l.x|<.>)
```

679 star : 692 unstar

Switched to Retina to get some more regexes in... Still not done.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## C# 6.0 (.NET Framework 4.6), 50 Bytes, 63,60%

```
bool s(string i)=>Regex.IsMatch(i,"ol|tar|l.x|ಠ");
```

Program i used for testing purposes:

```
void Main()
{
    var starred = @"C:\starred.txt";
    var unstarred = @"C:\unstarred.txt";
    
    var linesStarred = File.ReadAllLines(starred);
    var linesUnstarred = File.ReadAllLines(unstarred);

    var cls = linesStarred.Count();
    var clsc = 0;

    foreach (var line in linesStarred)
    {
        if ( s(line) ) clsc++;
    }
    
    var clu = linesUnstarred.Count();
    var cluc = 0;

    foreach (var line in linesUnstarred)
    {
        if (!s(line)) cluc++;
    }

    $"Starred {clsc}/{cls} correct ({(clsc/cls*100):0.00}%)".Dump();
    $"Unstarred {cluc}/{clu} correct ({(cluc /clu*100):0.00}%)".Dump();
    $"{(((clsc+cluc)/(decimal)(cls+clu))*100):0.00}".Dump();
}

bool s(string i)=>Regex.IsMatch(i,"ol|tar|l.x|ಠ");
```